# Gridded geometry in Windows doesn't restrict resizing

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Gridded toplevel windows in Windows XP doesn't seem to restrict the user from resizing in multiples of a number. It works in X, but not in Windows. I can resize to any pixel size.

Doesn't the Windows windows manager support it? Can i do it manually, maybe by binding some commands to the resize event of the toplevel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that it doesn't really work on Windows (this is also true for Mac OS X/Aqua) and it is because the window manager itself doesn't support the feature. You have to synthesize it with some scripts. *However* the real complication is that a typical gridded window is more than just the one gridded window; there's some extra space around it which can make the updated size go into the next grid size up and that makes the window expand a bit and resize again… and again and again…

Thus, we need a two-stage initialization, first measuring the real size of the extra space we have to allow for and only then applying the enforcement code.

```
package require Tk

proc initGrid {window w h} {
    # Do nothing for subwindows
    if {$window ne [winfo toplevel $window]} return

    lassign [wm grid $window] xcount ycount xstep ystep
    set wExtra [expr {$w - $xcount*$xstep}]
    set hExtra [expr {$h - $ycount*$ystep}]
    bind $window <Configure> [list resizeGrid $wExtra $hExtra %W %w %h]
}
proc resizeGrid {wExtra hExtra window w h} {
    # Do nothing for subwindows
    if {$window ne [winfo toplevel $window]} return

    lassign [wm grid $window] xcount ycount xstep ystep
    if {$w-$wExtra != $xcount*$xstep || $h-$hExtra != $ycount*$ystep} {
        set w [expr {($w - $wExtra)/$xstep}]
        set h [expr {($h - $hExtra)/$ystep}]
        wm grid $window $w $h $xstep $ystep
    }
}

pack [text .t -setgrid 1] -fill both -expand 1
bind . <Configure> {initGrid %W %w %h}
```

As you can see, this isn't particularly simple to get right!

Comment: Health Warning: I've not tried this on Windows, but it does work for me on OSX so there's a reasonable chance it will work for you too…

Comment: It works but it flickers while resizing. It's probably more stable to make the window non-resizable and make 4 button widgets for resizing. Or 2 text fields, or... Anyway, now that I know that I haven't missed anything or done something wrong, I can continue with my [level editor](http://troligen.se/wooden2.jpg). Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do much about the flickering without a lot of deep architectural work; the `<Configure>` event is how you get the size info in a timely way. (I _actually_ advise not using `-setgrid` at all and just dealing with what you get.)